# Is there an easy way to convert ISO 8601 duration to timedelta?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta, python-datetime

How can I convert an [ISO 8601 duration string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) to [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)?

I tried just instantiating `timedelta` with the duration string and a format string, but I get an exception:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> timedelta("PT1H5M26S", "T%H%M%S")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: str
```

---

<sub>For the reverse, see [Convert a datetime.timedelta into ISO 8601 duration in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168175).</sub>

Comment: *"a string of datetime.timedelta format"* doesn't make sense, I assume you mean a `datetime.timedelta` *object*. The standard lib doesn't have parsing for deltas, but there are packages on PyPI for you to `pip install` that do. If you want to know how to do it yourself, I think that's too broad for SO; you should have a go and see where (if anywhere!) you get too stuck to continue.

Comment: yes you are right. I want to convert it timedelta object. I can code my parser but, I am searching for if there is a simple solution.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as "too broad".  It is very focussed.

Comment: What is a `datetime.timedelta` ? Is it part of a package? can you give a concrete example of what you want vs what you got?

Answer (score 70):

I found [isodate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate) library to do exactly what I want

```
isodate.parse_duration('PT1H5M26S')
```

- You can read the source code for the function [here](https://github.com/gweis/isodate/blob/27cebc56a0f6a900eeb897512879d545095f410b/src/isodate/isoduration.py#L57-L130)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Pandas, you could use [`pandas.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html). The constructor accepts an ISO 8601 string, and [`pandas.Timedelta.isoformat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.isoformat.html) you can format the instance back to a string:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dt = pd.Timedelta("PT1H5M26S")
>>> dt
Timedelta('0 days 01:05:26')
>>> dt.isoformat()
'P0DT1H5M26S'
```

Comment: pandas >= 1.2.0 is required to parse an ISO 8601 duration strings, see the [pandas release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html#timedelta)

Comment: Pandas 1.2 has been released >2 years ago; so I hope that everyone has upgraded since then. (although I'm painfully aware that python 2.7 is being used by mostly data scientists...)

Comment: Note that contrarily to [Alkindus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976410), it returns `ValueError: Invalid ISO 8601 Duration format` on `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S` ([string source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO_8601&oldid=1214766350#Durations)).

Comment: That is because it isn't expressible as a timedelta, because the exact duration depends on the specific start or endpoint. In this case, `pandas.tseries.frequencies` might be useful (but note that OP specifically requested a timedelta)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution without a new package, but only works if you're dealing with a max duration expressed in days. That limitation makes sense though, because as others have pointed out ([1](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-March/133673.html)):

> Given that the timedelta has more than "a month's" worth of days, how
> would you describe it using the ISO8601 duration notation without
> referencing a specific point in time? Conversely, given your example,
> "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S", how would you convert that into a timedelta
> without knowing which exact years and months this duration refers to?
> Timedelta objects are very precise beasts, which is almost certainly
> why they don't support "years" and "months" args in their
> constructors.

```
import datetime


def get_isosplit(s, split):
    if split in s:
        n, s = s.split(split)
    else:
        n = 0
    return n, s


def parse_isoduration(s):
        
    # Remove prefix
    s = s.split('P')[-1]
    
    # Step through letter dividers
    days, s = get_isosplit(s, 'D')
    _, s = get_isosplit(s, 'T')
    hours, s = get_isosplit(s, 'H')
    minutes, s = get_isosplit(s, 'M')
    seconds, s = get_isosplit(s, 'S')

    # Convert all to seconds
    dt = datetime.timedelta(days=int(days), hours=int(hours), minutes=int(minutes), seconds=int(seconds))
    return int(dt.total_seconds())
```

```py
> parse_isoduration("PT1H5M26S")
3926
```

Comment: Note that the values are not necessarily integer (e.g. MPD manifests for DASH media streams for MP4 on the web), this presumes they all are and coerces to integer.

Answer (score 2):

Great question, obviously the "right" solution depends on your expectations for the input (a more reliable data source doesn't need as much input validation).

My approach to parse an ISO8601 duration timestamp only checks that the "PT" prefix is present and will not assume integer values for any of the units:

```py
from datetime import timedelta

def parse_isoduration(isostring, as_dict=False):
    """
    Parse the ISO8601 duration string as hours, minutes, seconds
    """
    separators = {
        "PT": None,
        "W": "weeks",
        "D": "days",
        "H": "hours",
        "M": "minutes",
        "S": "seconds",
    }
    duration_vals = {}
    for sep, unit in separators.items():
        partitioned = isostring.partition(sep)
        if partitioned[1] == sep:
            # Matched this unit
            isostring = partitioned[2]
            if sep == "PT":
                continue # Successful prefix match
            dur_str = partitioned[0]
            dur_val = float(dur_str) if "." in dur_str else int(dur_str)
            duration_vals.update({unit: dur_val})
        else:
            if sep == "PT":
                raise ValueError("Missing PT prefix")
            else:
                # No match for this unit: it's absent
                duration_vals.update({unit: 0})
    if as_dict:
        return duration_vals
    else:
        return tuple(duration_vals.values())

dur_isostr = "PT3H2M59.989333S"
dur_tuple = parse_isoduration(dur_isostr)
dur_dict = parse_isoduration(dur_isostr, as_dict=True)
td = timedelta(**dur_dict)
s = td.total_seconds()
```

⇣

```py
>>> dur_tuple
(0, 0, 3, 2, 59.989333)
>>> dur_dict
{'weeks': 0, 'days': 0, 'hours': 3, 'minutes': 2, 'seconds': 59.989333}
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(seconds=10979, microseconds=989333)
>>> s
10979.989333
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @r3robertson a more complete, yet not perfect, version

```
def parse_isoduration(s):
""" Parse a str ISO-8601 Duration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations
Originally copied from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976138/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-iso-8601-duration-to-timedelta
:param s:
:return:
"""

# ToDo [40]: Can't handle legal ISO3106 ""PT1M""

def get_isosplit(s, split):
    if split in s:
        n, s = s.split(split, 1)
    else:
        n = '0'
    return n.replace(',', '.'), s  # to handle like "P0,5Y"

s = s.split('P', 1)[-1]  # Remove prefix
s_yr, s = get_isosplit(s, 'Y')  # Step through letter dividers
s_mo, s = get_isosplit(s, 'M')
s_dy, s = get_isosplit(s, 'D')
_, s = get_isosplit(s, 'T')
s_hr, s = get_isosplit(s, 'H')
s_mi, s = get_isosplit(s, 'M')
s_sc, s = get_isosplit(s, 'S')
n_yr = float(s_yr) * 365  # These are approximations that I can live with
n_mo = float(s_mo) * 30.4  # But they are not correct!
dt = datetime.timedelta(days=n_yr+n_mo+float(s_dy), hours=float(s_hr), minutes=float(s_mi), seconds=float(s_sc))
return dt  # int(dt.total_seconds())  # original code wanted to return as seconds, we don't.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my modification(Martin, rer answers) to support `weeks` attribute and return milliseconds. Some durations may use `PT15.460S` fractions.

```
def parse_isoduration(str):
## https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976138/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-iso-8601-duration-to-timedelta
## Parse the ISO8601 duration as years,months,weeks,days, hours,minutes,seconds
## Returns: milliseconds
## Examples: "PT1H30M15.460S", "P5DT4M", "P2WT3H"
    def get_isosplit(str, split):
        if split in str:
            n, str = str.split(split, 1)
        else:
            n = '0'
        return n.replace(',', '.'), str  # to handle like "P0,5Y"

    str = str.split('P', 1)[-1]  # Remove prefix
    s_yr, str = get_isosplit(str, 'Y')  # Step through letter dividers
    s_mo, str = get_isosplit(str, 'M')
    s_wk, str = get_isosplit(str, 'W')
    s_dy, str = get_isosplit(str, 'D')
    _, str    = get_isosplit(str, 'T')
    s_hr, str = get_isosplit(str, 'H')
    s_mi, str = get_isosplit(str, 'M')
    s_sc, str = get_isosplit(str, 'S')
    n_yr = float(s_yr) * 365   # approx days for year, month, week
    n_mo = float(s_mo) * 30.4
    n_wk = float(s_wk) * 7
    dt = datetime.timedelta(days=n_yr+n_mo+n_wk+float(s_dy), hours=float(s_hr), minutes=float(s_mi), seconds=float(s_sc))
    return int(dt.total_seconds()*1000) ## int(dt.total_seconds()) | dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a regular expression to parse ISO 8601 time durations, without pulling in external dependencies.

The following works with common D/H/M/S designators. Supporting Y/M/W designators is not implemented.

```
import datetime
import re


def parse_iso8601_duration(duration: str) -> datetime.timedelta:    
    pattern = r"^P(?:(?P<days>\d+\.\d+|\d*?)D)?T?(?:(?P<hours>\d+\.\d+|\d*?)H)?(?:(?P<minutes>\d+\.\d+|\d*?)M)?(?:(?P<seconds>\d+\.\d+|\d*?)S)?$"
    match = re.match(pattern, duration)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid ISO 8601 duration: {duration}")
    parts = {k: float(v) for k, v in match.groupdict("0").items()}
    return datetime.timedelta(**parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev):

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> from pydantic import TypeAdapter
>>> timedelta_adapter = TypeAdapter(timedelta)
>>> td = timedelta_adapter.validate_python("PT1H5M26S")
>>> td
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3926)
```

For `datetime.timedelta` to ISO 8601 string [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77958030/1584915).

### Explanation

Pydantic is a data validation library. It accepts and outputs ISO 8601 strings [if declared type is `datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/api/standard_library_types/#datetimetimedelta). By using a [`TypeAdapter`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/api/type_adapter/), you can do validation/dump operations on a single type rather than on a Pydantic model.