# How to convert timedelta for plotly histogram?

Tags: python, time-series, plotly, histogram, x-axis

I want to plot histograms for **timedelta64** (example: `Timedelta('0 days 00:00:44.749500'`)

But in both cases, ploty.histogram() does not recognize the correct time but rather displays values (e.g., 50T 60T (See image)).

How do I have to convert the datetime/timedelta that plotly .histogram() recognizes the correct timeaxis? Thanks

```
fig = px.histogram(x=df_TT_redux["T_delta"],color=df_TT_redux["event_source"],log_y=True)
```

[image]

EDIT:
THanks to LittlePanic404
converting to ISO Format gives some interesting results. I guess I have to tweak that still a bit.

using

```
import isodate
df_TT_redux["T_delta3"]=[isodate.duration_isoformat(x) for x in df_TT_redux["T_delta"]]

fig = px.histogram(x=df_TT_redux["T_delta3"],color=df_TT_redux["event_source"],color_discrete_map=color_discrete_map,log_y=False,log_x=False,nbins=100)
```

[image]

However,
another way of solving this could be this:

```
df_TT_redux["T_delta2"]=df_TT_redux["T_delta"]/pd.Timedelta("1 hour")
```

or
`.../pd.Timedelta("1 minute")`. Depending on your case

[image]

Comment: "Plotly auto-sets the axis type to a date format when the corresponding data are either ISO-formatted date strings or if they're a date pandas column or datetime NumPy array." So you have to convert it in iso format, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168175/convert-a-datetime-timedelta-into-iso-8601-duration-in-python

Comment: You could also use the `total_seconds` method of `timedelta` to convert it into a numeric type and label the axis accordingly.